# mobile version filter is not showing properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made filter based on selection in input. It shows only items with same category on click. On desktop version when I click for example "Others" it will list only tr with Others in category but when I resize on mobile version and press filter, so nothing happen. All tr's are still showing. Really don't have idea what is difference between mobile and desktop version when JS is working with same code in both views.

```js
highlightRows = () => {
    let oddRows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr.show')
    oddRows.forEach((row, index)=> {
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
            row.style.background = '#f1f1f1'
        } else {
            row.style.background = '#fff'
        }
    })
}


const filterOptions = () => {
    const option = document.querySelector("#filter").value;
    const selection = option.replace('&', '')
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#body1 > tr");
  console.log(rows.length);
    
    rows.forEach(row => {
        let td = row.querySelector("td:last-child");
        let filter = td.innerText.replace('&', '');
        if (filter === selection) {
            row.className = 'show'
        } else {
            row.className = 'hidden'
    }

    });
    highlightRows()
};
document.getElementById("filter").addEventListener("change", filterOptions);
```

```css
.table-filters {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
.table-filters a {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.table-filters a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.table-filters select {
  background: #fff;

  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 12em;
  height: 2.5em;
}

table.stats {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
tbody tr.show {
  display: table-row;
}
tbody tr.hidden {
 display: none;
}
table.vypis {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.vypis > caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table.vypis > tr.vypis-riadok {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table.vypis th,
table.vypis td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table.vypis th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  table.vypis {
    border: 0;
  }

  table.vypis > caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  
  table.vypis > thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  
  table.vypis tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  
  table.vypis td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  table.vypis td::before {

    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  table.vypis td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-filters">
        <select id="filter">
          <option disabled selected value="none">Categories</option>
          <option>Hobby</option>
          <option>Others</option>

          
        </select>
      </div>
      <table class="vypis">
        <caption>Pohyby na účte</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Refer</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Category</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="body1">
          <tr class="vypis-riadok">
            <td scope="row" data-label="refer">[[X04_riadok_1_popis_transakcie]] <br> [[X10_riadok_2_popis_transakcie]]</td>
            <td data-label="date">[[X02_riadok_1_datum]]</td>
            <td data-label="price">[[X08_riadok_1_suma]] €</td>
            <td data-label="category">Others</td>
          </tr> 
                    <tr class="vypis-riadok">
            <td scope="row" data-label="refer">[[X04_riadok_1_popis_transakcie]] <br> [[X10_riadok_2_popis_transakcie]]</td>
            <td data-label="date">[[X02_riadok_1_datum]]</td>
            <td data-label="price">[[X08_riadok_1_suma]] €</td>
            <td data-label="category">Hobby</td>
          </tr> 
                    <tr class="vypis-riadok">
            <td scope="row" data-label="refer">[[X04_riadok_1_popis_transakcie]] <br> [[X10_riadok_2_popis_transakcie]]</td>
            <td data-label="date">[[X02_riadok_1_datum]]</td>
            <td data-label="price">[[X08_riadok_1_suma]] €</td>
            <td data-label="category">Others</td>
          </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well, but the problem is with rule `display: block`, which is in the `media query`. in the `table.vypis tr` selector. This rule overrides another block hiding rule. You need to remove `display: block` out of `table.vypis tr`.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

...
table.vypis tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
}
...

}
```

Or a second solution:

Add! `!important` to rule `display: none`, selector `tbody tr.hidden`. It should look like this:

```
tbody tr.hidden {
 display: none!important;
}
```

**I advise you to use the second solution!**